# Reading a txt file into a Linked List, but Printing only prints first node in the List

Tags: c

I'm writing this code for a college project, and I need to load this text file into a Singly Linked List. But When printing it only prints the first line in the file (the first node in the LinkedList).
Lines in the .txt files are as follows:

VOLKSWAGEN GOLF 2017 WHITE 120000

VOLKSWAGEN GOLF 2017 BLACK 121000

VOLKSWAGEN POLO 2018 ORANGE 95000

VOLKSWAGEN CADDY 2015 BLACK 145000

VOLKSWAGEN CADDY 2015 BLACK 145000 etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!
See code:

```
struct sCar{
char manufacturer[15];
char model[15];
int year;
char colour[10];
float price;
struct sCar *nextInLine;
};
//Changing name for convenience.
typedef struct sCar * LIST;
typedef struct sCar * NODE;

int main()
{
    printf("\n\n** START **\n\n");
    LIST carsList;
    carsList = MakeEmpty(NULL); //Initialized. (carsList) is now the Head.   

    NODE temp;
    temp = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct sCar));
    FILE *fPtr;
    if ((fPtr = fopen("cars.dat", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("File could not be opened");
    else
    {
        fscanf(fPtr, "%s %s %d %s %f", &temp->manufacturer, &temp->model,     
               &temp->year, &temp->colour, &temp->price);
        if(carsList->nextInLine == NULL)
        {
            carsList->nextInLine = temp;
            temp->nextInLine = NULL;
        }
        else
        while(fscanf(fPtr, "%s %s %d %s %f", &temp->manufacturer, &temp->model, &temp->year, &temp->colour, &temp->price) == 5)
        {
        NODE newNode;
            newNode = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct sCar));
            fscanf(fPtr, "%s %s %d %s %f", &newNode->manufacturer, &newNode->model, &newNode->year, &newNode->colour, &newNode->price);
            temp->nextInLine = newNode;
            temp = newNode;
            temp->nextInLine = NULL;
        }
    }
    printNodes(carsList);
    return 0;
}

LIST MakeEmpty(LIST L)
{
    if(L != NULL)
        DeleteList(L);
    L = NULL;
    L = (LIST)malloc(sizeof(struct sCar));
    if(L==NULL)
        printf("Out of Memory. Can't Allocate List.");
    else
        L->nextInLine = NULL;
    return L;
}


void printNodes(LIST L)
{
    LIST temp;
    temp = L->nextInLine;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nManufacturer: %s", temp->manufacturer);
        printf("\nModel: %s", temp->model);
        printf("\nYear: %d", temp->year);
        printf("\nColour: %s", temp->colour);
        printf("\nPrice: %.2f\n", temp->price);
        temp = temp->nextInLine;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    struct sCar {
       char manufacturer[15];
       char model[15];
       int year;
       char colour[10];
       float price;
       struct sCar *nextInLine;
    };

    typedef struct sCar * LIST;
    typedef struct sCar * NODE;

   void printNodes(LIST L)
   {
       while(L != NULL) {
           printf("\n\nManufacturer: %s", L->manufacturer);
           printf("\nModel: %s",     L->model);
           printf("\nYear: %d",      L->year);
           printf("\nColour: %s",    L->colour);
           printf("\nPrice: %.2f\n", L->price);
           L = L->nextInLine;
       }
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("\n\n** START **\n\n");
        LIST carsList;
        carsList = malloc(sizeof(struct sCar));

        FILE *fPtr;
        if((fPtr = fopen("cars.dat", "r")) == NULL)
            puts("File could not be opened");
        else
        {
            NODE NEXT = carsList;
            while(NEXT != NULL && fscanf(fPtr, "%s %s %i %s %f", &(*NEXT->manufacturer), &(*NEXT->model), &(*NEXT).year, (*NEXT).colour, &(*NEXT).price) != EOF) {
                NODE newNode;
                newNode = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct sCar));
                NEXT->nextInLine      = newNode;
                NEXT                  = newNode;
            } 
            printNodes(carsList);
        }
    }
```

I'll leave it to you to find out how you want to stop the loop. last item printed on the console is an empty sCar with no fields set.

Comment: @Abdul-QaderHaddad can you mark the question as answered. thanks!

Comment: I'm still new to StackOverFlow haha, Done!